# Adjusting time-series before a sudden increase(the reason & time of the increase are known)

Tags: r, time-series, adjustment, statsmodels

There are 2 increases in magnitude (one between feb and march, and one at the beginning of september) [image]

(the chart has daily resolution btw)

Assuming weekly seasonality, is it ok to get the exact day when the increase was noticed and the day 1 week earlier, compute a scaling factor new/old and scale everything before the increase happened with that scaling factor ?

How is this operation usually called ? How do people usually do this, is it just this sort of scaling or is there a more correct(and perhaps more sophisticated) approach for this ?

What would you use for adjusting this time-series in either [R](https://www.r-project.org/) or Python and [statsmodels](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels) ? Is there a worked out example of this somewhere that I could read or could you describe one here ?

(The two increases have a common cause. The chart shows counts of certain posts on a website. At the times of the two increases, there was a new roll-out of a collector and as a result, more data started coming in. So the scaling I'm trying to do is trying to estimate how the time-series would have looked prior to the increases if the current collection were in place from the beginning, from January 2015)

Comment: In statsmodels you can just add a indicator variable (0 before, 1 after the change date) as explanatory variable `exog` to ARMA, SARIMAX and similar models. Adding an additional linear trend could be appropriate to avoid that the indicator variable also captures some trend effects. A not very clean example of adding explanatory variables (using splines for seasonal effects) is at https://gist.github.com/josef-pkt/1ea164439b239b228557 The ARMAX version implemented in statsmodels is a linear model with ARMA errors.

Comment: (Out of sample prediction in ARMA with explanatory variables requires statsmodels master or the yet unreleased 0.7 version because it fixes a timing bug.)

Answer (score 2):

Detecting and incorporating Level Shifts (Step Shifts) is an integral part or both non-causal and causal modelling. The term Intervention Detection is often used. Some software implementations restrict identification to non-causal models while others do not. See http://www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf for a seminal article and search here for relevant posts using the string "intervention detection" . Typical output would include "what the series would have looked like without the intervention" . These are often called the "adjusted values" .

There may be a "de facto date" and a "de jure date" to the intervention, often coinciding but sometimes not due to dynamics in the series. If one knows the start date then one can simply add an indicator variable ( 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1..) to reflect that knowledge and then use the estimated coefficient for that variable as the adjustment factor.

If you knew that an intervention had occurred at a particular point in time you could estimate a model of the form where I is the 0/1 intervention variable is used in conjunction with the ARIMA component.

For example if you had a pulses at two points in time (39 and 21) the augmented data matrix might look like .

[image]

[image]

Comment: How would you add this indicator variable in practice ? Could you please  write a bit more about how this is done in practice ?

Comment: what does the formula you wrote above mean and where can I read more about it ?

Comment: The formula includes m distinct series , each one a 0/1 series stored in the appropriate  I vector. The polynomial L(B) contains the weights/coefficients for the particular j series. . If the model is a constant plus a pulse indicator plus a random error we would have m=2 , L11= 3.2 and L21=10.0 and I1=(1,1,1,1,1,.....1) and i2=(0,0,0,0,1.0.0.0...0) where the "1" represents the point in time of the pulse that was 10 units higher than the overall mean of 3.2